# Не подключается Mysql

Tags: python, django, freebsd, mysql

Пытаюсь поменять sqllite на mysql в settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql',
    'NAME': 'djangodb51',                    
    'USER': 'djangodb51',
    'PASSWORD': '*******',
    'HOST': 'localhost',   
    'PORT': '3306',                     
} 
}
```

Выдаёт

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x2921fbcc>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 28, in get_validation_errors
    from django.db import models, connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 45, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named mysql.base
```

В Pythone новичок пока, подскажите, куда рыть?
Система Freebsd 9.1, Python2.7, Django 1.5.0.

Попробовал на новой машине: система Freebsd 10, Python2.7, Django 1.7.0.

То же самое.

```
 File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 197, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 125, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 300, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 166, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 242, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 126, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
```

Хотя с sqlite работает нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, у вас даже в стектрейсе подсказка есть

```
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
```

Для mysql попробуйте 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',